# how to get dates and times on AEST time zone?

Tags: r

I am based in Melbourne Australia.

I am trying to get dates and times in AEST times rather than AEDT or UTC time zones.

Is there a way that I can specify either on every usage of date/time function or environmental setup that all dates/times would be based on Australian Eastern Standard Times rather than UTC or Australian Eastern Daylight Savings Times.

I was trying to use lubridate package or even POSIXct/lt date functions but I couldn't get it to give me dates/times in AEST times.

Best regards

Deepak Agarwal

Comment: Can you give an example of some datetimes that are giving you problems? `as.POSIXct()` has a `tz=` argument for specifying timezones manually. You could specify a timezone that doesn't observe daylight savings, such as backward hicks like me in Brisbane.

Comment: Deepak, does the answer help you? It's customary to "accept" an answer if it works, or explain why it doesn't.

Comment: Where are the checkmarks? I am new to this system!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first problem might be assuming that "AEST" is found. It is not.

```
now <- Sys.time()
now
# [1] "2018-02-19 23:37:28 UTC"
attr(now, "tzone") <- "AEST"
now
# Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'AEST'
# [1] "2018-02-19 23:37:28 GMT"
```

You might be wondering what is available for timezones. It might be helpful to read [`?timezones`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html), in which is shown two related functions:

> `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)`
>
> `OlsonNames()`

If you look in `OlsonNames()` (it's kind of long, btw), you'll notice:

```
on <- OlsonNames()
length(on)
# [1] 593
on[ grepl("Australia", on) ]
#  [1] "Australia/ACT"         "Australia/Adelaide"    "Australia/Brisbane"   
#  [4] "Australia/Broken_Hill" "Australia/Canberra"    "Australia/Currie"     
#  [7] "Australia/Darwin"      "Australia/Eucla"       "Australia/Hobart"     
# [10] "Australia/LHI"         "Australia/Lindeman"    "Australia/Lord_Howe"  
# [13] "Australia/Melbourne"   "Australia/North"       "Australia/NSW"        
# [16] "Australia/Perth"       "Australia/Queensland"  "Australia/South"      
# [19] "Australia/Sydney"      "Australia/Tasmania"    "Australia/Victoria"   
# [22] "Australia/West"        "Australia/Yancowinna"
```

If I'm correct, then you'll be able to use `"Australia/Queensland"`. Now, you can do

```
attr(now, 'tzone') <- "Australia/Queensland"
now
# [1] "2018-02-20 09:37:28 AEST"
```

Many functions that deal with timestamps will accept `tz=` or a related argument. Many of them (I don't know if "all" is correct, so I'll stick with "many") honor the `"TZ"` environment variable:

```
Sys.getenv("TZ")
# [1] ""
Sys.time()
# [1] "2018-02-19 23:43:11 UTC"
Sys.setenv(TZ = "Australia/Queensland")
Sys.time()
# [1] "2018-02-20 09:43:11 AEST"
```

(You could also use `"Etc/GMT+10"` for code-golf or other reasons, which works for hour-aligned timezones. However, looking at the return from `OlsonNames()`, you won't have the [half-hour-aligned timezones present in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia).)

**Edit:** Oops, should be `"Etc/GMT-10"` as an option, not "+10".

Comment: `Etc/GMT+10` might be safest since it will *never* be bound to daylight savings whims. It's probably bound to be introduced eventually in Qld.

Comment: Using `"Australia/Queensland"` does not introduce daylight savings on my console. For instance, in `Sys.time() + (1:12)*(60*60*24*30)`, the hour never varies, whereas after `Sys.setenv(TZ="US/Eastern")` (for instance), it does vary. Am I missing something in the question or in R's application of this timezone?

Comment: It won't now, because Qld doesn't have daylight savings. For now. There are calls for it nearly every year and I wouldn't be surprised if you ran the same code in the year 2022 you'd get AEDT. GMT+10 will still be GMT+10.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize they were considering *implementing* daylight savings. Perhaps I'm affected by the calls in some US states to get rid of DST. Fair point. Wonder how `"Australia/Melbourne"` will behave if that happens.

Comment: Thanks loads everyone. That was exactly what I was looking for. I think I might choose the 'GMT + 10' option - perhaps the safest and most deterministic. Btw, is this supposed to be 'O1sonNames()' or '01sonNames()' - as it didn't seem to work on my system. I will check again anyhow!

Comment: attr(now, "tzone") <- "Etc/GMT+10"
> now
[1] "2018-02-20 14:15:40 -10"
> attr(now, "tzone") <- "Australia/Queensland"
> now
[1] "2018-02-21 10:15:40 AEST"
Why does the first one give me yesterday's date at 2.15 pm whilst the "Australia/Queensland" tzone gives the correct time?

Comment: `Etc/GMT-10` is the correct tz database name. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database : "In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed"